# Interesting things happening to my badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

So a little while ago, I noticed my recent achievements button was green denoting I had gotten a new badge. I clicked on it and it displayed no new badges, but when I went to my profile it showed that my most recent badge earned was the Excavator one. I clicked on it to show which post I had gotten it from, but it only displayed the post I had originally gotten the badge from, and nothing indicating why I had gotten a new one. Now, when I look at my recent badges, it shows the Convention badge which I earned before I supposedly got the Excavator badge. Also my total bronze badge count on my profile for Arqade shows me having 50 of them, but if I count them manually, I only have 49 total.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this was broken and fixed.

Per [Excavator and Marshal badges are being awarded over and over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshall-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over)

> We just did a major revamp of how badges are awarded behind the scenes to drastically reduce the load on SQL Server. It now takes advantage of some pre-compute work we're doing to track badge progress in the profile.
>
> However, I screwed up 2 queries...

Comment: okay so as of tonight, the only evidence of this ever happening would be all the meta posts and confused people. got it